# How is it that StackExchange allows moderators that believe attacking an idea is the same as attacking a person?

Tags: discussion, support

Also, how do you delete your StackExchange account?

Comment: Here is information on deleting your account. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: Can you provide an example of when this occurred? I'm guessing this relates to an answer of yours that was deleted and which you recently rolled back an edit to?

Answer (score 10):

Welcome back to Politics.SE. I presume you're referring in your question to my final deletion vote on your [answer here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/57514/28994) a couple of months ago. Firstly, note that this took place before I was elected as a community moderator, so I was only acting then in my role as a high-reputation user.

Nevertheless, if your answer was posted again today in its current form, I would still be in favour of taking similar action. While I appreciate that this is clearly an emotive issue for you, your answer cast aspersions about the motives of the user who asked the question, referred to the question as "nutty", and was needlessly  provocative, referring to a public figure throughout as "Orange Man". That is not the level of discourse which is acceptable on this site.

Even after these references were edited out by regular users as well as a moderator, your answer was still, in my opinion, needlessly aggressive, and still referred to a public figure as a "zombie candidate, who actually hates this country", leading me to cast a deletion vote along with two other community members.

I'm afraid I take issue with the assertion you've made about my beliefs in your question title; I don't feel like my actions here warrant such a claim.

To address the question you've posed, Stack Exchange has trusted the community to elect its own moderators, and voters in said election had access to my history of content moderation, as well as the opportunity to pose questions to moderator candidates. Most of my actions as a moderator are available for the community at large to review, and those that aren't can be scrutinised by my fellow moderators as well as Stack Exchange employees.

I'm sorry that you feel like this unfortunate incident has led to you feeling unable to continue to contribute to our site. As Joe W mentioned, information on account deletion can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

Comment: The A under discussion is certainly far from 'good', and I won't even challenge the deletion as such. But I notice that your rationale for doing so explained here is concerning me. Note that a mod left in "zombie" and emphasised "don't insult other users here". More important is that *"needlessly aggressive"* was your main motivation for delvoting? To what & in which way aggressive? — To generalise away from that A – this is a) personal opinion/taste b) nowhere (ie [help]) to be found as a valid reason for users to delete a post? Or is there a different policy at work *here?* (doc'd on meta?)

Comment: @LangLangC the answer, in my opinion, violates the [CoC](https://politics.stackexchange.com/conduct) which requires, for example, that contributions refrain from being unfriendly and not include name-calling or personal attacks. Yes, this is often subjective.

Comment: Well, the CoC itself is problematic. Here, "unfriendly langauge" is the invitation of arbitrariness to avoid. But in this case, I agree on given *the examples* for 'unfriendly' in it, ie in 'treating other users' was present (case A) and should've been edited out (general case again)—but still no need to always jump to deletion. & your rationale should be edited into this A as well, but as perhaps relate more directly to this metaQ *title,* as it seems to me that Philipp's edit is as much meant with it as the deletion votes. Ie: these diffs over interpreting 'attack' might need a better rule?